# adminhtml system settings addColumn upload image

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I'm trying to add an image upload button to a custom "`Custom_Module_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Table`".

I have found the following site: https://www.integer-net.com/how-to-create-tables-in-magento-system-configuration/

Here they show how to create a drop-down menu. So I should use 'renderer' to create a custom field. But how to create a image upload field?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can try it- for renderer set a template which will have input file field, to save the  image in directory you have to use ajax on file upload

Answer (score 1):

To display `import` option you need to only pass                             `<frontend_type>file</frontend_type>` for example,

```
      <upload_file>
         <label>Upload Image</label>
         <comment>Upload your Image from here</comment>
         <frontend_type>file</frontend_type>
         <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_file</backend_model>
         <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo</upload_dir>
         <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">admin-config-uploads</base_url>
         <sort_order>1</sort_order>
         <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
         <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
         <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </upload_file>
```

If you want to change upload Image location then you can change path from

```
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">sales/store/logo</upload_dir>
```

`sales/store/logo` is image location under media directory